# On the mathematical convention used to talk about biconditional proofs

Tags: soft-question, notation, proof-writing, self-learning, article-writing

Given $P \Longleftrightarrow Q$, the following does apply:

- $P \Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to:
  $P$ is a sufficient condition for $Q$,
  $Q$ is a necessary condition for $P$.
- $Q \Rightarrow P$ is equivalent to:
  $Q$ is a sufficient condition for $P$,
  $P$ is a necessary condition for $Q$.

Still, when we read a proof of a statment of the form of a biconditional, we find the authors referring to one direction as ***THE*** sufficient condition, and the other as ***THE*** necessary condition, when – after all – as arises naturally from what written above, it is basically relative.

Still, I found that in general (I do not remember an instance where I noticed a different pattern) we have that:

> - ($\Longrightarrow$) is associated to the **necessary** condition (***only if***),
> - ($\Longleftarrow$) is associated to the **sufficient** condition (***if***).

---

Here there is an ***example*** from Dudley's "Real analysis and probability" that should make more perspicuous what my point is all about:

> **2.1.3. Theorem:** [Let $(S, \mathcal{T})$ be any topological space] A set $U \subset S$ is open iff for every $x \in U$ and net $x_i \to x$ there is some $j$ with $x_i \in U$ for all $i \geq j$.
>
> ***Proof:***
>   “Only if” follows from the definition of convergence of nets.
>   “If”: suppose a set $B$ is not open. Then for some $x \in B$, by (b) there is a net $x_i \to x$ with $x_i \notin B$ for all $i$.
>
> *(Here this is part (c) of the theorem, and the (b) in the proof that is mentioned is another result previously obtained that still is irrelevant for my point)*

As it can be noticed, indeed Dudley uses "only if" to refer to a certain direction, while "if" to refer (obviously) to the opposite direction. Still, this looks to me as a convention, namely the one described above.

---

Hence, is my induction concerning this convention correct?
Is true that this is the standard convention in mathematics when writing about biconditionals?

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are all exactly the same:

- If $P$, then $Q$
- $P \Rightarrow Q$
- $P$ is sufficient for $Q$
- $Q$ is necessary for $P$
- $Q$ if $P$
- $P$ only if $Q$.

The following are all exactly the same:

- If $Q$, then $P$
- $Q \Rightarrow P$
- $Q$ is sufficient for $P$
- $P$ is necessary for $Q$
- $P$ if $Q$
- $Q$ only if $P$.

To show $$A \text{ iff } B,$$ it doesn't matter whether we phrase it as "A iff B" or "B iff A". However, once the theorem is stated as "A iff B", then we may say "We prove the 'if' direction" and we mean we are showing "A if B": that is, "B implies A". Similarly, if we prove the "only if" direction in that case, that means we are showing "A only if B", or "A implies B".

Comment: I think that this answer does not touch the point of my question pretty much in the same way in which a previous answer (deleted) did not do it. The question concerns the ***convention*** that mathematicians use when they write a proof concerning a biconditional and they split in two parts. Indeed, you can divide it and use arrows, but some authors use the "if"/"only if" dicothomy, or they talk about necessary or sufficient condtion, but again, this is a convention. Is the convention I pointed out correct? This is the question, and this does not answer it.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. You may split the biconditional into "if P, then Q; if Q, then P", or into "P is sufficient for Q; P is necessary for Q", or into "P is sufficient for Q; Q is sufficient for P", or into "P if Q; Q is necessary for P", or any combination of "something from list 1; something from list 2".

Comment: Exactly, but the point is not what can you can do, or the logical nature of the biconditional (otherwise I would have put the tag "logic"). The point of the question is that when you open a book on math, and there is a theorem that is a bicondition with its proof, the authors obviously split it. Sometime they uses arrow to point which direction they are addressing. Some others, they put in parentheses **(only if)** or **(if)**, or they talk about focusing on the **necessary** condition or on the **sufficient** condition, still *to signal which direction they are addressing*.

Comment: But, as for example you point out in your answer, and I do the very same thing in the body of my question, necessary/sufficient (likewise if/only if) is sort of relative when we look at a biconditional. Hence, it is indeed a convention that they associate one direction with necessary/"only if", and the other with sufficient/"if". Then the point is, is the convention I described correct?

Comment: Please see the example I added in the body of the question from Dudley to see what my point is all about.

Comment: "A iff B" is interpreted as two distinct questions: "A if B", and "A only if B". To show the "only if", we show that "A only if B", or "B is necessary for A". To show the "if", we show that "A if B", or "B only if A", or… I still fail to see what you're asking.

Comment: I think I actually see your point. Btw, my point is that $A$ *iff* $B$ means that the two are actually interchangeable ($B$ *iff* $A$ is literally the same), and hence it is relative from which one we *start* to look at the necessary/sufficient dicothomy. Hence, there is the need to look at a convention. I hope I clarified my position.

Comment: Btw, if you randomly edit your answer, I will be happy to upvote it (when I downwoted it, I didn't know I was locked in that decision until you edited it) and accept it. I am sorry, my fault.

Comment: Done - added another paragraph.

Comment: I corrected a typo at the very end of your answer ("A only if B" $\equiv$ "A implies B"). Still, I just realized (I know, after quite a while) that there is something missing that goes back to what I referred as convention, and you did not say anything about it. Namely, how do we deal with **necessity** and **sufficiency**. That is, when we find a biconditional proof of $A \Longleftrightarrow B$, and the authors write *"For the **necessity**, etc etc"*. Which side are they dealing with? For necessity, I think they usually refer to $A \implies B$. Am I right?

Comment: It should be clear from context, but I think they usually mean "$A$ is necessary for $B$": that is, "if $B$ then $A$", or $B \Rightarrow A$. (I'm not totally convinced of that, though.)

Comment: Actually, I took a look on google.books, and apparently the *convention* (based also on previous occurrences I found around) is that $A \Leftrightarrow B$ is the same as **necessity**. Btw, I am glad that now you see what I was actually referring to when I was talking about some sort of a convention when dealing with this. :)

Comment: @Kolmin People only use ambiguous terms when their meaning is clear from context, in my experience.